# Android saves image twice

Tags: android

I'm making a screenshot of my few programmatically but somehow the image is saved in the /TestProject/ folder but also in the normal picture folder. Does anyone have a clue why this is happening. (And is there a change that Android's normal picture folder shows all images all together?)

```
OutputStream out;

    root.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(root.getDrawingCache());
    root.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);


    /* Preparation ==================================== */
    // Find the SD Card path
    File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    // Create a new folder in SD Card
    File dir = new File(path.getAbsolutePath() + "/TestProject/");
    dir.mkdirs();
    /* ================================================= */

    // Create a name for the saved image
    File file = new File(dir, (new Date().getTime() + ".jpg"));

    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);

        // Compress into png format image from 0% - 100%
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, (new Date().getTime() + ".jpg"), null);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Farm art saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `insertImage()` method also creates a thumbnail for the inserted image. There is a probability that you're seeing the thumbnail and the inserted image.

If you want to force a scan of the image by the media store, you should use the `scanFile()`[0] method instead.

[0] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29